# Is it possible to have vertical rather than horizontal GTK tabs in gvim?

Tags: vim, tabs, gtk

`gvim` can represent multiple *windows* with horizontal tabs by using the `-p` (or `--remote-tab-silent` if in a single session) option:

[Horizontal tabs in gvim http://void.nu/~gammy/img/tabs_hori.png](http://void.nu/~gammy/img/tabs_hori.png)

Is it possible to show the tabs in a **vertical column** in  a *GTK*-fashion (ie, *not using an additional vim buffer*, but actually using the GUI)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean - have the tab line, where the names *main.pde*, *LevelFont.h* and so on ... are displayed - show in vertical fashion?

No, that is not possible.

You can use *:ls* to list the buffers, you can use some plugin maybe to show the list of tabs in a separate window, but you cannot change Vim's native tabline to show differently.

Comment: Do you know if there's any unofficial patchset to add this functionality?

Comment: @games - No. not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing tabs. They are not to represent a list of files, they are to represent different window layouts. If you forget about tabs and use multiple buffers (you already do have them) in one tab, you will likely to be able to find a plugin that can display a list of buffers in a vertically split window, but it is very unlikely that you will find the same for tabs. At least minibufexplorer has this functionality (with `let g:miniBufExplVSplit={width}`).

Comment: They represent a list of **buffers**, right. Poor wording on my part. As I said, I'm explicitly interested in out-of-buffer solutions(ie using the GUI)

Comment: @gamen - No, tabs in Vim do not represent buffers. They represent windows, in which (via splits) many buffers can "be loaded", so to say.

Comment: Ach! Poor wording again! I'll adjust my question accordingly for future reference.